# A riemannian metric is in a neighborhood of $g$ (?)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What do we mean by this:

"A Riemannian metric $g_1$ is in a small *$C^{l+1,\alpha}$ neighborhood* of the metric $g$" ?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $C^{l+1,\alpha}$ refers to a [Hölder space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%c3%b6lder_condition#H.C3.B6lder_spaces). This is the space of functions with $l+1$ derivatives such that the $(l+1)^{\textrm{st}}$ derivative is Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$.

The statement that $g_1$ is in a $C^{l+1,\alpha}$ neighborhood of $g$ is a statement that, for $g_1$, the first $l+1$ derivatives (including the $0^\mathrm{th}$, i.e. the value of $g_1$ itself) *and* the Hölder coefficients (see the link above) of its $(l+1)^{\textrm{st}}$ derivative are close to those of $g$.